# Node js get values from array

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have this code in the server side to send to the client which users disconnect from the system:

```
data = [usuariosConectados,socket.nickname];
io.sockets.emit('usuarioDesconectado',data);
```

In the client side I have this:

```
websocket.on("usuarioDesconectado",procesarUsuarios);

function procesarUsuarios (mensaje)
{
console.log(mensaje);
    $('#users').html('');
for(u=0; u<mensaje.length; u++)
{
    for(var user in mensaje[u])
    {
        $('#users').append($('<p>').text(mensaje[u][user]));
    }
}
}
```

The `console.log(mensaje)` shows this:

```
[{hola:"hola", lol:"lol"}, "Oscar"]
```

With this I know that the user Oscar is out of the system and hola and lol are still in.

The problem is in this part:

```
$('#users').append($('<p>').text(mensaje[u][user]));
```

this code shows the connected users but also the disconnected user like

```
O
s
c
a
r
```

How can I get the connected users separated from the disconnected?

Answer (score 0):

i found my solution:

```
$('#users').html('');
if (mensaje[1] != null)
{
$('#chatInsite').append($('<p>').html('<span>'+ '<strong>' + mensaje[1] + " desconectado</strong></span> "));   
for(i in mensaje[0])
    {
        $('#users').append($('<p>').text(mensaje[0][i]));
    }
$('#chat').animate({scrollTop: $('#chatInsite').height()},800);
}
else
{
    for(i in mensaje[0])
    {
        $('#users').append($('<p>').text(mensaje[0][i]));
    }
    console.log("Usuario Nulo");
}
```